# JTextField

Tags: java, focus

how to set the focus in the JTextField??

Answer (score 3):

The abstract class ***Component*** which ***JTextField*** extends provides a ***requestFocus()*** method.

```
JTextField jtf = getTextFieldFromSomewhere();
jtf.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [requestFocusInWindow()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow())

requestFocus() can be used but is discouraged as it is platform dependent.

See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to call `grabFocus()`
Example: `jTextField.grabFocus();`

Answer (score 0):

JTextField extends JComponent so JTextField would have [this method](http://www.ermalaev.spb.ru/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus()).

Answer (score 0):

We can gain focus in any jComponent with `grabFocus()`

```
 jtextField.grabGocus();
 jlist.grabFocus();
 jCombobox.grabFocus()
 etc.
```